# How to properly cast when using generics in java methods?

Tags: java, generics

I have an assignment to implement my own version of Collections.fill() and Collections.reverse(). The algorithms are simple enough, but I'm getting a little bit lost in the generics involved, specifically when I need to do casting.

My original idea is something like:

```
public static void reverse(List<?> a_list) {
    int list_size = a_list.size();
    ListIterator<?> left_to_right = a_list.listIterator();
    ListIterator<?> right_to_left = a_list.listIterator(list_size);
    ? temp_variable;

    // ..doing some stuff

    right_to_left.set(temp_variable);

}
```

But of course I can't declare the temp as type "?". Declaring as "Object temp_variable" makes sense, but then the call to set(temp_variable) at the end won't work (since the ListIterator won't take Object -- because the list is likely not type List<Object>).

It makes sense to me, then to declare temp as an Object, and cast the ListIterators:

```
ListIterator<Object> left_to_right = 
    (ListIterator<Object>) a_list.listIterator();
ListIterator<Object> right_to_left = 
    (ListIterator<Object>) a_list.listIterator(list_size);
```

The compiler gives me unchecked cast warnings when I do this, but I can't think of how this would break, given my implementation. Is there any danger in doing this?

Then in Collections.fill(), I originally wanted to do something like:

```
public static <E> void fill(List<? super E> a_list, E an_object) {
    ListIterator<E> an_iterator = (ListIterator<E>) a_list.listIterator();

            // ..doing some stuff
    an_iterator.set(an_object);

}
```

This gives an unchecked cast warning, too. And thinking about it more, even though I still get a warning, would it be safer to do a cast like:

```
ListIterator<Object> an_iterator = (ListIterator<Object>)a_list.listIterator();
```

If the generic type of the list is actually a superclass of E, it should be safer to cast to a ListIterator for a List of Objects, and not to a ListIterator for a subclass of the list's generic type, shouldn't it?

Any advice would be appreciated...I don't think our instructor wanted us to get this involved, but I'd like to understand generics better.

Comment: Using generics is supposed to help you *AVOID* casting, isn't it?  And doesn't using "Object" in a generic kind of contradict the whole *POINT* of using generics in the first place?

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) Please read these links:  http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html    2) Please consider eliminating the "?" wildcard syntax until you feel comfortable with basic generics.  Then use "?" syntax only if you really need it.  IMHO...

Comment: Thanks for the links, @paulsm4. I think I've solved my two problems: using a single ? doesn't make sense, since a method with a single type-parameter is really the same signature anyway after erasure, and then I can use the type-parameter; and, I now realize I can use <? super T> as a type for my ListIterator (which I didn't realize was allowed).

Comment: If you must use wildcard syntax, then remember "PECS": http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't cast, and don't use `?`. Use type-parameterized methods; something like this.

```
public static <T> void reverse(List<T> a_list) {
    int list_size = a_list.size();
    ListIterator<T> left_to_right = a_list.listIterator();
    ListIterator<T> right_to_left = a_list.listIterator(list_size);
    T temp_variable;

    while(left_to_right.nextIndex() < list_size / 2) {
        temp_variable = left_to_right.next();
        left_to_right.set(right_to_left.previous());
        right_to_left.set(temp_variable);
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, since I'm implementing Java's Collections.reverse(), I need to use Java's signature, which is `static void reverse(List<?> list)`. I'd definitely rather just use your version.

Comment: No, *all* generics now use the "?" wildcard syntax.  That doesn't mean *you* can't use a concrete class.  Again, please read the links I cited above.

Comment: Hmm, ok, that makes sense. Just so I'm clear, what you're saying is that `static void reverse(List<?> list)` is really the same signature as `static <T> void reverse(List<T> list)`, after erasure?

Comment: @Trent after erasure, the type is replaced with its upper bound, so in your example, **yes.** However, after erasure, `List<T extends SomeInterface>` is the same as `List<SomeInterface>`.

Answer (score 3):

Where you have a generic type of the form `Xyz<?>` then the `?` will stand for some particular (but not necessarily denotable) type. (This isn't true for `Abc<Xyz<?>>`.) Method calls can infer types, which enables us to give a label to the type using a "capture helper" method (thanks @newacct).

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list) {
    reverseImpl(list);
}
private static <T> void reverseImpl(List<T> list) {
```

You can now define locals as type `T`.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, but do you mean to pass list (not type) to the private method?

Comment: +1 this is called the "capture helper", and is exactly for such situations where a wildcard is sufficient for the signature, but internally you need an actual parameter. And since other people shouldn't care about the internal stuff, you can hide it using this method

Comment: @newacct Ah yes. Capture was the word I was looking for.